# If I set the header z-index and position, my content's height will be eaten

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

The question as the title, I set my webpage's header as

```
<img src="imgs/header.jpg" style="box-shadow: 0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1); position: fixed; z-index: 9;" alt="">
```

the header image's size is 3330x230px, and it will responsive with different device, therefore after the header's TopSlider's height will be eaten because of the header z-index and position.

Is anyone amazing god could help me how to write the javascript to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please define how it should look at the end so you will say "problem is sovled"

Comment: Maybe add a `margin-top` equal to the height of the `header` . And add it to the next element. ( slider i guess ) and use the `window.onresize` event. If you want us the help you further please share the code you have tried to solve this. ( Including js ) . SO is not a ' free ' code making forum/site/community

Comment: Welcome to SO, no need of js here its because of `fixed` position which created DOM empty of getting space of header, @MihaiT Suggestion will work like charm

Comment: @Awais js will be needed as the height of the header will decrease/increase depending on the size of the screen. So the OP cannot know the exact height of the header. That's why you would need js to ' read ' the height of the header.

Comment: @MihaiT he can set fixed height like eg:`200px` and use `object-fit:cover` to make it work :)

Comment: Dears, you can see it will be a blank on the topbanner, and can't be responsive. https://jsfiddle.net/jzs2v1rn/1/

Comment: Since you know the aspect ratio of your image, you should be able to easily use the _padding-bottom hack_ to reserve appropriate space. https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/, https://www.andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html